# Higher order expansion term of Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff (BCH) formula

Tags: group-theory

I want to calculate unto 20th order, the expansion of Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula. [In Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) up to 4th order expansion is available.

Is it possible to get the expansion term up to 20th order using recursion?

Comment: Start by understanding the [WP integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula#An_integral_formula) and matching the explicit orders provided. This question belongs to the [math.se]. Why is it here?

Comment: The BCH formula is used in Physics extensively, especially in the cases  where Schrodinger dynamics is involved.

Comment: Normally, in QM one applies the *degenerate* CBH formula, where the commutator is central, and so higher orders are trivial or simple. If not, one uses group theoretical methods like the Van Kortryk identity, e.g., for the oscillator group.

Comment: Ok, that's great to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. What you are trying to do is solve for $Z(X, Y, t)$ such  that $e^Z$ will agree with $e^{tX} e^{tY}$ up to $O(t^{20})$. Let's say you know the first $n$ terms so that
\begin{equation}
Z(X, Y, t) = \sum_{i = 0}^n Z_i(X, Y) t^i + O(t^{n + 1}).
\end{equation}
What you do next is write
\begin{equation}
e^{tX} e^{tY} = \exp \left ( \sum_{i = 0}^n Z_i(X, Y) t^i + \alpha t^{n + 1} \right )
\end{equation}
and expand both sides up to and including the $O(t^{n + 1})$ term. This will give a linear equation for the unknown $\alpha$ which you can solve. Now you know the first $n + 1$ terms.